# Limit bandwidth using tc, iptables, and htb

Tags: debian, iptables, user-management, bandwidth-control, tc

I'm running a Debian server and was wondering if there are good resources out there, to which you can point me, where I can read about traffic limitations.

I have a couple of users sharing one server. Each month we only get lets say 1 TB of bandwidth (in and out). Therefore I need to split the bandwidth up equally.

I've read about iptables, tc, htb, but I can't seem to find a really good tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the ultimate HowTo: http://lartc.org/howto/index.html